# Cyclic Interface Error when using orElseThrow

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, guava

Using [`Guava's ClassPath`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0-rc2/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html) I am trying to initialize classes located in a specific package, but I want to use the constructor to initialize as that doesn't propagate exceptions. So this is what I worked out to get constructors:

```
ClassPath.from(classLoader).getTopLevelClasses("test.package").stream()
    .map(ClassPath.ClassInfo::load)
    .map(Class::getConstructors)
    .map(Arrays::stream)
    .map(constructorStream -> constructorStream
        .filter(constructor -> constructor.getParameterCount() == 0)
        .findAny()
        .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new)
    );
```

However, this gives an error in InteliJ just simply stating Cyclic interface. I think I know what a Cyclic interface is, but I'm not sure why this would cause that error. As far as I know as long as the return type is known (which for `orElseThrow` it has a return value in this case as `Constructor<?>`) then throwing an unchecked exception should be fine. If I use `orElse(null)` then the error goes away. What's going on here and how may I throw the RuntimeException I want to throw?

Comment: What happens if you prefix the `orElseThrow` with the specific type? `.<RuntimeException>orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new)`

Comment: The error is removed and now works as intended. Why though? Shouldn't `X` already be defined by the provided exception?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using a compiler that doesn't do the type inference very tightly. In Eclipse, it works without the explicit type argument. In Oracle's `javac` it complains about an unreported exception.

Comment: That seems to be yet another type inference limitation/bug of the compiler. However, I don’t get the benefit of using `orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new)` over a simple `get()`. Invoking `get()` on an empty `Optional` will raise a `NoSuchElementException` which is already a subclass of `RuntimeException` and it will even have the meaningful message `"No value present"`. So what’s making a message-less direct instance of `RuntimeException` better?

Comment: I wasn't going to initialize a `RuntimeException` directly it was just to show that I couldn't throw one. In my actual code I was going to throw a custom `RuntimeException` with a very specific message.

Comment: FYI it's actuall "cyclic inference". It's because the compiler can't infer the type you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runtimeexception is thrown from within the map lambda. The acual exception could be handled inside the Stream api.

To avvoid this you can use the flatMap method to make the current stream replaced by the combined streams provided to your flatMap method. This is commonly used when combining streams. See also [adam bien's example on flatmap.](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_8_flatmap_example)

In this example the exception does not have to go through the streaming api - so you could also use checked exceptions and not be limited by the signature in the Stream interface which has no throws clause.

```
    ClassPath.from(classloader).getTopLevelClasses("test.package").stream()
            .map(ClassPath.ClassInfo::load)
            .map(Class::getConstructors)
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .filter(constructor -> constructor.getParameterCount() == 0)
                    .findAny()
                    .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
```